# Hover animation "jumps" while hovering out

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to achive a simple animation on hover in css, but while hovering off, the animation jumps and makes it look silly. Is there a way to avoid that?
My wish would be that it is colapsing the same way it originaly transformed.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/misah/pen/abzRXvL

```css
.item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  transition: 800ms;
}

.item::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  background-color: grey;
  transition: transform 800ms ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover::after {
  transform: scaleY(2);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `transform-origin: bottom;` is only applied when the item is hovered. When not hovered it falls back to the default - `center`. Move the rule to the declaration of the `::after`.

```css
.item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  transition: 800ms;
}

.item::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  background-color: grey;
  transition: transform 800ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.item:hover::after {
  transform: scaleY(2);  
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Ahh, too fast for me ;)

Comment: Holly cow this was a fast answer and the right one. Thanks, I will mark it as correct as soon as stackoverflow is allowing me.